# How to find the bounded variation function for a Riemann-Stieltjes representation of a functional in $C \,[a,b]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, stieltjes-integral

The Riesz's representation theorem says that every bounded linear functional $L$ on $C \,[a,b]$ can be representated by a Riemann - Stieltjes integral:
$$L(f) = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)d(\alpha(t))$$
where $\alpha$ is a bounded variation on $[a,b]$.

So, i have the following linear functional $L: C\,[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R};\;L(f) =f(x_0)$ with $x_0 \in [a,b]$ fixed.

How i can find the bounded variation function $\alpha$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Define $\alpha: [a,b] \to \Bbb{R}$ by
$$
\alpha(t):= \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{ if } a \leq t <x_0 \\
1 & \text{ if }  x_0 \leq t \leq b
\end{cases}
$$
Then,
$$
\int_{a}^b f d\alpha  = f(x_0)
$$